# Pynini install fails

Tags: pynini

I am getting the error message below when I try to install pynini

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda-4.11.0-py3.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO' -> '/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda-4.11.0-py3.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO.c~

Command used:

conda install -c conda-forge pynini

I am using ubuntu. Is there a workaround?

Comment: use `sudo`? install separate python in a location that does not require `sudo`? It's often a good idea to leave the baked-in python alone as the distro may depend on it.